# IOS Application duplication

Tags: ios, iphone, duplicates, whatsapp

I would like to duplicate a application on IOS, so i've already tried by editing the CFBundleIdentifier, CFBundleDisplayName, CFBundleExcecuteble and CFBundleName.

Then i recompile the info.plist, and zip the archive to a .IPA

When the IPA is being installed (ipa installer, ifunbox), the installer says: "No valid ipa"

Application is Whatsapp version 2.8.7

Thanks for any comments.

Comment: you work for Whatsapp ? :O

Comment: Thats not what my first question says.. :P I want to duplicate this application so it's possible to have 2 whatsapp applications on one account. This will be also possible for KIK, Viber and many other applications.

Comment: Apple has protections in place for tampering with the info.plist.  The OS will not load an app that has a tampered info.plist.

Comment: I don't think it is appropriate to publish link to download the tampered IPA file here, considering it is purchased content.

Comment: Thanks for the sugestion borrrden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to modify `CFBundleDisplayName` and `CFBundleIdentifier` in the `Info.plist` file inside the IPA.
BUT in order to install you also need to have `AppSync` installed on the device, which removes checks during installation

Comment: don't know if it makes any sense but it's noteworthy to add that what i did was to backup an app from phone, edit the info plist inside the ipa as already mentioned, BUT when I backed up, the files iTunesMetadata.plist and iTunesArtwork were replaced with empty folders having the same names. maybe that counts, too. backedup using 911pc suite.

Answer (score 2):

Whatever you are trying to do is not leagal. And there is no simple way to do it even if it can be done. There is something called [Code Signing](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/AppSigning.html), so simply changing Bundle Identifier won't help you.

Comment: @mvz040": if it's legal or not depends on the terms of use and legislation... It most certainly isn't cosher: you payed for the use or **original** app as-is, not for the right to tamper with it.